# GITHUB magento changed via ftp

Tags: git, magento, github, ftp

i have Github installed in our magento directory, however i want to make css changes direct via ftp rather through GIThub.

When i make the changes through FTP they dont show up. I changed the file permissions but to no preval.

please advise many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's important to point out that if your Github installation is setup to update the working directory (where Magento is installed), your CSS edits made using FTP will most likely be overwritten when a new commit/push is made.

With that being said, here is a checklist for you to go through.

1. Make sure you're modifying the correct CSS file in the correct template directory.  You can verify by doing a View Source in your browser, and ensuring that the file you're editing is the one being loaded.
2. After modifying the file and saving it to the server, flush the Magento caches under `System > Cache Management`.  It's a good idea to disable all caching when doing heavy frontend modifications.
3. Make sure to do a cache refresh in your browser by hitting `CTRL + F5` on your keyboard.  This will force the browser to re-download all of the files, instead of loading them from the browser cache.

Comment: Hi Thanks Tried all mentioned but the site has still reflected the changes, any further suggestions

Comment: Are you merging your CSS files at all?  Check `System > Configuration > Developer > CSS Settings` and seeing if `Merge CSS Files` is set to yes or no.

Comment: it is set to no, shall i set to yes?

Comment: i set it to YES and cleared caches but still changes not updated

Comment: Go to the CSS file URL in your browser and see if the changes you are making are present in the actual file.

Comment: Then your edits aren't being uploaded correctly through FTP.  If the file isn't updated, the style won't change.

Comment: could this be because Github has been installed in the directory?

Comment: Git shouldn't interfere with the file, unless someone is actively pushing changes to it.  You just aren't updating the file correctly, that's the gist of this issue.